# convert a given curl request into ajax request

Tags: ajax, curl, watson, watson-conversation

I have a `curl` request :

`curl -X POST -u "uname":"pwd" --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hello there\"}}"` "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/YourWorkspaceID/message?version=20XX-XX-XX"

what is the equivalent `ajax` request for this `curl` request?

l have tried ,

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/XXX...XXX/message?version=20XX-XX-XX",        
    data: "{ \"input\": {\"text\": \"Hello\"}} ",          
    headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
    u : { 'uname' : 'pwd' },
    success:function(response)
    {
        console.log("Success!!");
    },

    error : function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        console.log("Status of error message" + status + "Error is" + error);
    }   

    });
```

Please correct the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the user/password in an Authorization header, similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11960692/3331845

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/XXX...XXX/message?version=20XX-XX-XX",        
    data: "{ \"input\": {\"text\": \"Hello\"}} ",          
    headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
},
    success:function(response)
    {
        console.log("Success!!");
    },

    error : function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        console.log("Status of error message" + status + "Error is" + error);
    }   

    });
```